# How to pass additional parameters but not in url when hitting mvc controller from javascript window open

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
<a href="#" onclick="anchorClicked('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Url") %>', '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"infoToSend") %>')"> </a>

anchorClicked= function (Url, infoToSend) {
    window.open(Url, '_blank');
    return false;
}
```

This opens the Url i intend to open. It hits at my MVC controller at this URL. The problem is i need to send "infoToSend" parameter to this MVC controller. How can i do that here?

I don't want to do this by changing URL/in query string.

Comment: You could try sending the data using `AJAX`, and specifically with `POST` method, and that won't do anything extra to your URL.

Comment: Depends on what you need these params to do. Please give more details on use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $.ajax , to pass your information. you can send data in data defined in $.ajax as in example below:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'any_name': 'value'},
                url: "controller/action",
                success: function (result) {

                    }
    });
```

Comment: If you see origin question, I have direct URL: by which i open new page. So i don't want to use url: "controller/action". I want something like url: Url which i already have. This would further redirect me to MVC. Any way to do this?

Its not working currently when i write url: Url.

Comment: haven't used fiddle much. will give it a try. In the meantime, I would try to rephrase the problem:

I have url to which i want to redirect to so i don't want to use url: "controller/action", instead i want to have something like url: Url

Comment: I am not sure how i can do this in fiddle. I am very new to UI. When I write url: Url, its hitting the controller but i am not redirected to the desired page.

Comment: Do you want to send data and open link in new window in mvc? is that so?

Comment: yes. The link i already have(being passed to function as input) redirects me automatically to MVC. The problem is link is not opening.

Comment: try this:

<a href="@Url.Action("RunReport", "Performance", new { reportView = Model.ReportView.ToString() })" 
   type="submit" 
   id="runReport" 
   target="_blank"
   class="button Secondary">
     @Reports.RunReport
</a>

Comment: What is this? Why can't i do it simply with url: Url. Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97606/discussion-between-sahil-and-dashang-g-makwana).